# Can UIImagepickercontroller have multiple Instances at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Here I want to use both front cam and back cam at a time in uiimage picker controller to capture a image, so I am planing to use two objects of cam one with front cam and other with back cam , Is it possible to have multiple objects of camera at a time.can any one help me please.

Comment: I dont think, u can do it...

Comment: @preetam asking or telling ?

Comment: Is it possible with avcam

Comment: No you cant there are two conditions back and front and you can select only one of them...

Comment: what I am telling is i am creating 2 objects of image picker in one obj i am using front cam and in 2nd obj i am using rare cam

Comment: @kmReddy: where you are planing to see capture view at a time from front n back cam?

Comment: I kept two views on mainview one for front cam and the other for back cam